# What is the best way to loop through sql (SQL or Asp.net C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, t-sql

I am creating a list to send an e-mail to.  The individual who is logged in has a field in the database of who they report to (unless there is an error or they report to no one).

So for instance if I am logged in and clicked the submit button in SQL it would say I report to 'John Doe'

I then need to grab who 'John Doe' reports to and add that to the list.  I need to keep climbing the list until we reach the top of the company (the GID will be blank or null).

Using me as an example, I report to `'John Doe'` who reports to `'Tom Doe'`.  Tom reports to no-one his `usrReportsTo` field is like this `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`.

If the usrReportsTo field is `""` or `NULL` or `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'` the loop should terminate.

Here is the sql I used.

What is the cleanest/neatest/most effecient way to perform this loop and is it better to do it in SQL or ASP.net C#?

```
select usrReportsTo from dbo.CVT_Users_usr, usrEmailAddress
WHERE RTRIM(usrFirstName) + ' ' + RTRIM(usrLastName) = 'James Wilson' 
-- Returns 'James Wilson' + email

SELECT RTRIM(usrFirstName) + ' ' + RTRIM(usrLastName) as Name, usrEmailAddress, usrReportsTo from dbo.CVT_Users_usr
WHERE usrGID = '38922F83-4B6E-499E-BF4F-EF0B094F47F7'
-- Returns 'John Doe' + email + reportsTo

SELECT RTRIM(usrFirstName) + ' ' + RTRIM(usrLastName) as Name, usrEmailAddress, usrReportsTo from dbo.CVT_Users_usr
WHERE usrGID = 'FB8F4939-3956-4834-9D89-D72AFB8BF3E0'
-- Returns 'Tom Doe' + email + reportsTo
```

Edit #3

Working copy of SQL just doesn't return 100% true data.

with cte
AS
(
select usrGID, RTRIM(usrFirstName) + ' ' + RTRIM(usrLastName) as Name, usrEmailAddress, usrReportsTo from dbo.CVT_Users_usr
union all
select u.usrGID, RTRIM(u.usrFirstName) + ' ' + RTRIM(u.usrLastName), cte.usrEmailAddress, cte.usrReportsTo from dbo.CVT_Users_usr u
    inner join cte on u.usrReportsTo = cte.usrGID
)
    select * from cte
    where Name = 'James Wilson'

-- Returns

usrGID                                    Name        usrEmailAddress   usrReportsTo
E1DAFC11-BE35-4730-9961-68EEF8D85DE4    James Wilson                38922F83-4B6E-499E-BF4F-EF0B094F47F7
E1DAFC11-BE35-4730-9961-68EEF8D85DE4    James Wilson    john@1234.com   FB8F4939-3956-4834-9D89-D72AFB8BF3E0
E1DAFC11-BE35-4730-9961-68EEF8D85DE4    James Wilson    tom@1234.com    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Shouldn't the usrGID and name match the same way usrEmailAddress and usrReportsTo does?  I tried chaanging the sql to be cte.USRGID and cte.Name but it gave the max recursion error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What database backend do you use, that makes a difference in this kind of code.

Comment: @HLGEM Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `common table expression` you can generate the complete result set in one SQL statement (via a recursive join), thus avoiding any looping at all.

A basic example with the key fields

```
create table #CVT_Users_usr (usrGid uniqueidentifier, usrEmailAddress varchar(50), usrFirstName varchar(20), usrLastName varchar(20), usrReportsTo uniqueidentifier)

insert #CVT_Users_usr values    
('38922F83-4B6E-499E-BF4F-EF0B094F47F7' , 'james@wilson.com','james','wilson', 'E1DAFC11-BE35-4730-9961-68EEF8D85DE4'),
('E1DAFC11-BE35-4730-9961-68EEF8D85DE4', 'john@doe.com','john','doe', 'FB8F4939-3956-4834-9D89-D72AFB8BF3E0'),
('FB8F4939-3956-4834-9D89-D72AFB8BF3E0', 'tom@doe.com','tom','doe' ,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
('FE6899A5-63BA-42B7-A70E-011711A5FAC6', 'ken@ken.com','ken', 'kenneths', 'FB8F4939-3956-4834-9D89-D72AFB8BF3E0')

declare @id uniqueidentifier
select @id = usrGid from #CVT_Users_usr where usrFirstName='james' and usrLastName='wilson'

;with cte as
(
select usrGid, usrEmailAddress, usrFirstName, usrLastName, usrReportsTo from #CVT_Users_usr
union all
select u.usrGid,  cte.usrEmailAddress, cte.usrFirstName, cte.usrLastName, cte.usrReportsTo 
from #CVT_Users_usr u
    inner join cte on u.usrReportsTo= cte.usrGid
)
    select usrFirstName + ' ' + usrLastName, usrEmailAddress  from cte
    where usrGid=@id

drop table #CVT_Users_usr
```

Comment: Hrm, I'm going to add a edit to the post.  The SQL wont run keep saying the multi part identifier cannot be found. @podiluska

Comment: @JamesWilson, his code does work (I ran it on my server), so it must be something in how you implemented it. Can you edit your question to show what code you ran to get that error? Also, are you by chance in compatibility mode for SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @JamesWilson I've revised it adding the first/lastname fields.

Comment: I was able to get a working copy going, can post the new code if needed.  But only some of the data returned is what it should be.  And when I change u.USRGID to cte.USERGID it gives me the max recursion error.  Going to delete older stuff from OP and add new SQL im using. @podiluska

Comment: It's because you're doing the WHERE clause on the name - you're asking it to return a bunch of James Wilsons - filter on the ID and it works - reedited to use your column names

Comment: I don't have access to the GID at login time without adding extra code to get the GID.  I guess I can just not select the GID and name and only use the e-mail since that is all i really need.  It seems to work from that perspective.

Comment: Even better, I used your updated code and it worked like a charm!  Thank you very much. :) @podiluska